# How to install numpy on win7 64bit for python 2.7.8?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, windows-7-x64

I was trying unofficial binaries here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy
but I still don't know which one is good for me. Any ideas?

Comment: What are your requirements? Can you add more information about what you're trying to do?

Comment: Why not use [Winpython](https://winpython.github.io/)? It offers what you want out of the box.

Comment: you can ask google for pythonxy, which includes most of the relevant packages for scientific purposes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

numpy‑MKL‑1.9.1.win‑amd64‑py2.7 should do.